# Make arraylists from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist that was made from importing a file. I now want to separate this list into smaller arraylists by category. The code I have for the original arraylist is as follows:

```
public class TriviaGamePlayer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
File gameFile = new File("trivia.txt");

List<TriviaGame> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<TriviaGame>();
Scanner infile = new Scanner(gameFile);
String lastKnownCategory = "";

while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
    String currentLine = infile.nextLine();

    if (!currentLine.isEmpty()) {
        TriviaGame currentQuestion = new TriviaGame();

        if (currentLine.endsWith("?")) {
            currentQuestion.setCategory(lastKnownCategory);
            currentQuestion.setQuestion(currentLine);
            currentQuestion.setAnswer(infile.nextLine());
        } else {
            currentQuestion.setCategory(currentLine);
            currentQuestion.setQuestion(infile.nextLine());
            currentQuestion.setAnswer(infile.nextLine());
            lastKnownCategory = currentLine;
        }
        triviaQuestions.add(currentQuestion);
    }
}

infile.close();



System.out.println(triviaQuestions);
```

This will display [category=Arts & Literature, question=What are bongo drums traditionally held between for playing?, answer=The knees] There are a bunch more followed by it in different categories. From here i want to make different arraylists for each category and be able to pick out category, question and answer.
Thanks

Comment: Don't just tell us what you want. Tell us what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, thats the thing. Im a student and Im stuck at this point. The first hurdle was to be able to make the arraylist sort in some logical order. I dont know how to make arraylists from arraylists and make them in a way i can manipulate parts of it.

Comment: May I ask why you need to seperate the arraylist into smaller arraylists? Sorting the arraylist according to the category of the question should be enough to be able to work simple with the arraylist. If you really want many arraylists, then maybe you should directly store the category-question-anser triples into the category-specific arraylist. And create multiple arraylists at the beginning :)

Comment: "From here i want to make different arraylists for each category and be able to pick out category, question and answer." - Can you make your question a bit specific? There are many ways to solve your problem. What have you tried?

Comment: @StevenEck I think you're getting too hung up on it being an array list. You have a get() and an add() operation. From that you should be able to come up with some sort of logic. Coming up with the logic, also requires no java knowledge. Once you get how it's going to be done, then you can start writing java.

Comment: HashMap<String, ArrayList<TriviaGame>>

Comment: @MarkKennedy What im basically doing is making a trivia game. I need to have arraylists store the questions and answers in a way that will allow me to compare them with a user input answer while only offering one random question per category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
public class TriviaGamePlayer {

static class TriviaGame {
  String category;
  String question;
  String answer;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
File gameFile = new File("trivia.txt");

List<TriviaGame> triviaQuestions = new ArrayList<TriviaGame>();
Scanner infile = new Scanner(gameFile);
String lastKnownCategory = "";
Map<String, List<TriviaGame>> map = new HashMap<String, List<TriviaGame>>();

while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
    String currentLine = infile.nextLine();

    if (!currentLine.isEmpty()) {
        TriviaGame currentQuestion;
        if(map.containsKey(lastKnownCategory) == false)
          map.put(lastKnownCategory, new ArrayList<TriviaGame>());

        map.get(lastKnownCategory).add(currentQuestion = new TriviaGame());

        if (currentLine.endsWith("?")) {
            currentQuestion.setCategory(lastKnownCategory);
            currentQuestion.setQuestion(currentLine);
            currentQuestion.setAnswer(infile.nextLine());
        } else {
            currentQuestion.setCategory(currentLine);
            currentQuestion.setQuestion(infile.nextLine());
            currentQuestion.setAnswer(infile.nextLine());
            lastKnownCategory = currentLine;
        }
        triviaQuestions.add(currentQuestion);
    }
}

  infile.close();

  System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

Basically you can even remove `triviaQuestions.add(currentQuestion);` and just reference to the map. In the map you will have all your questions grouped by lastKnownCategory value.

Comment: ahh, sorry. this is groovy groovy groovy ;) fixing. Thanks.

Comment: map[lastKnownCategory].add(currentQuestion = new TriviaGame());  is giving me an error, in eclipse suggests that I change it to an int?

Comment: What error in eclipse?

Comment: @archer should be map.get(lastKnownCategory). Too much python from you

Comment: from my above comment eclipse tells me: can not convert String to int, then suggests that i change lastKnownCategory to an int.

Comment: @StevenEck java thinks that if you say map[..] that you are talking about an array and wants an integer index. The syntax is just wrong. See my last comment

Comment: When I change from put to get i get this error: The method get(Object) in the type Map<String,List<TriviaGame>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<TriviaGame>)

Comment: @StevenEck not from put to get, change map[lastKnownCategory] to map.get(lastKnownCategory). The put is correct.

Comment: :) Please, use @Cruncher suggestion ;) I'm really too much groovy guy and trying my code in `groovyConsole`.

Comment: Code changed. Use it.

Comment: Got it, now I can just grab what i need from it to make my random questions. Ill have to check out the API on maps. Never seen those

Comment: @StevenEck Maps are sorcery, that's all you need to know lol. You'll be even more amazed when you learn that they have constant time inserts and gets and deletes. (kind of)

Comment: LOL, thats what I'll tell my professor :)